# Processes getting killed mysteriously

Tags: ssh, centos, putty

So i'm accessing to my CentOS machine at Digital Ocean through ssh using putty. I made a rest API that listens to incoming POST messages and decodes it sending them to somewhere (it doesn't really matter). I have also a bash script that acts like a flume agent and stores data on a mysql database. What happens is that those processes are being killed mysteriously after a while.

Some time after I "kill" the ssh connection, (obviously the scripts keep on running as though i only kill the connection not the machine itself) it kills those 2 processes leaving no trace.

Do you think that this is a RAM issue? I have 512MB.

Comment: *Some time after I "kill" the ssh connection, (obviously the scripts keep on running as though i only kill the connection not the machine itself)* - not obviously; processes started from a shell get killed when the shell exits. That's why things like screen and tmux and mosh exist - so you can have long running processes and reconnect to them when your connection fails. Are your processes particularly written to be background daemons / services?

Comment: Well it seems you're right. I'm new to this kind of thing so i think i misundertood the all thing. I'm trying screen right now. Thanks TessellatingHeckler